# is Ballerina array operation such as push and pop are thread safe?

Tags: ballerina

Can anyone help to confirm that ballerina array operations such as pop and push are thread/strand safe?

```
signedMessages.push(payload);

signedMess = signedMessages.pop();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the array operations aren't thread safe. You can use [locks](https://ballerina.io/v1-1/learn/by-example/locks.html) to ensure the accesses are safe. But note that this is an experimental feature and will likely change considerably in future versions.

Comment: Hmm, so what is the best/recommended way as of now to ensure the concurrent safe access?

Comment: The current mechanism we have for ensuring safe access is lock. You can use the above array functions within a lock block to ensure safe access. Note that the array should be a global one and the lock applies to the array itself as a whole (i.e., doesn't lock at an individual array element level).